# SwiftUI view parameters not updating after sheet view dismissed

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that displays multiple images fetched from Firebase in a VStack. Each image is a button, the button opens a sheet and it displays the image and text that goes with it. When I dismiss the sheet and press on a different image the same data comes up. How do I refresh these paramaters

VStack View with images as buttons:

```
@State var dic = OrderedDictionary<String, UIImage>()

VStack (alignment: .center) {
                
                ForEach(dic.keys, id: \.self) { dicObject in

                    Button {
                        showingSheet.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(uiImage: dic[dicObject]!)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                        GalleryViewSpecific(image: dic[dicObject]!, url: dicObject)
                    }
                }
            }
```

View specific image view used by .sheet

```
//@State var image: UIImage
@State var image: UIImage
@State var url: String
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Button("Press to dismiss") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.black)
            
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                .cornerRadius(20)
            
            Text(url)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            
        }
    }
    .background(Color.black)
}
```

Comment: Move your `sheet` outside the `ForEach` and use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`

Comment: If I move sheet outside of the ForEach 'dicObject' is not in the scope

Comment: Please update your code to show a minimal example that reproduces the issue; ideally a `struct ContentView` that someone can paste into Xcode and run. Please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: @Bart that is why you use the `sheet(item:)` form I suggested. You'll set the `item` to your object inside the `Button` action

Comment: `ForEach` is not a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the displayed item when you tap the button inside the `ForEach`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Item: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let text: String
    }
    
    let items = [Item(text: "1"), Item(text: "2")]
    @State var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    selectedItem = item
                }) {
                    Text(item.text)
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { selectedItem in
                Text(selectedItem.text)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `onDismiss` -- this will happen automatically

Comment: @jnpdx even nicer; edited.